# SONAR always shows LOC as 0

Tags: c#, sonarqube, code-analysis, stylecop, lines-of-code

I am new in SONAR and I just doing POC to implement SONAR. 
Currently I am doing code analysis trough StyleCop in my solution and every time that I execute the sonar-runner I do not get any LOC.

Am I missing something to setup?

The sonar-project.properties content looks like this.

```
# required metadata
sonar.projectKey=paccar.PoC
sonar.projectName=PoC
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sources=.
sonar.language=cs

sonar.dotnet.key.generation.strategy=safe

# External tools to deactivate when the solution is not compiled
sonar.fxcop.mode=skip
sonar.gendarme.mode=skip
sonar.gallio.mode=skip
sonar.ndeps.mode=skip
```

The rules that I have saved in sonar Settintgs/C# StyleCop looks like this

```
<StyleCopSettings Version="105">
  <Analyzers>
    <Analyzer AnalyzerId="StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules">
      <Rules>
        <Rule Name="ElementDocumentationMustHaveSummary">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="PartialElementDocumentationMustHaveSummary">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ElementDocumentationMustHaveSummaryText">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="PartialElementDocumentationMustHaveSummaryText">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ElementDocumentationMustNotHaveDefaultSummary">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ElementParametersMustBeDocumented">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ElementParameterDocumentationMustMatchElementParameters">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ElementParameterDocumentationMustDeclareParameterName">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ElementParameterDocumentationMustHaveText">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ElementReturnValueMustBeDocumented">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ElementReturnValueDocumentationMustHaveText">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="VoidReturnValueMustNotBeDocumented">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="GenericTypeParametersMustBeDocumented">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="GenericTypeParametersMustBeDocumentedPartialClass">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="GenericTypeParameterDocumentationMustMatchTypeParameters">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="GenericTypeParameterDocumentationMustDeclareParameterName">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="GenericTypeParameterDocumentationMustHaveText">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="PropertySummaryDocumentationMustMatchAccessors">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="PropertySummaryDocumentationMustOmitSetAccessorWithRestrictedAccess">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ElementDocumentationMustNotBeCopiedAndPasted">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="SingleLineCommentsMustNotUseDocumentationStyleSlashes">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="DocumentationTextMustNotBeEmpty">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="DocumentationTextMustContainWhitespace">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="DocumentationMustMeetCharacterPercentage">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ConstructorSummaryDocumentationMustBeginWithStandardText">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="DestructorSummaryDocumentationMustBeginWithStandardText">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="DocumentationHeadersMustNotContainBlankLines">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="IncludedDocumentationXPathDoesNotExist">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="IncludeNodeDoesNotContainValidFileAndPath">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="InheritDocMustBeUsedWithInheritingClass">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ElementDocumentationMustBeSpelledCorrectly">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="FileMustHaveHeader">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="FileHeaderMustShowCopyright">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="FileHeaderMustHaveCopyrightText">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="FileHeaderMustContainFileName">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="FileHeaderFileNameDocumentationMustMatchFileName">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="FileHeaderMustHaveValidCompanyText">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="FileHeaderFileNameDocumentationMustMatchTypeName">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
      </Rules>
      <AnalyzerSettings />
    </Analyzer>
    <Analyzer AnalyzerId="StyleCop.CSharp.LayoutRules">
      <Rules>
        <Rule Name="OpeningCurlyBracketsMustNotBeFollowedByBlankLine">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
      </Rules>
      <AnalyzerSettings />
    </Analyzer>
    <Analyzer AnalyzerId="StyleCop.CSharp.MaintainabilityRules">
      <Rules>
        <Rule Name="ArithmeticExpressionsMustDeclarePrecedence">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ConditionalExpressionsMustDeclarePrecedence">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
      </Rules>
      <AnalyzerSettings />
    </Analyzer>
    <Analyzer AnalyzerId="StyleCop.CSharp.NamingRules">
      <Rules>
        <Rule Name="ElementMustBeginWithLowerCaseLetter">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="FieldNamesMustNotBeginWithUnderscore">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
      </Rules>
      <AnalyzerSettings />
    </Analyzer>
    <Analyzer AnalyzerId="StyleCop.CSharp.OrderingRules">
      <Rules>
        <Rule Name="DeclarationKeywordsMustFollowOrder">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ProtectedMustComeBeforeInternal">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="InstanceReadonlyElementsMustAppearBeforeInstanceNonReadonlyElements">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="SystemUsingDirectivesMustBePlacedBeforeOtherUsingDirectives">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="UsingAliasDirectivesMustBePlacedAfterOtherUsingDirectives">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
      </Rules>
      <AnalyzerSettings />
    </Analyzer>
    <Analyzer AnalyzerId="StyleCop.CSharp.ReadabilityRules">
      <Rules>
        <Rule Name="PrefixLocalCallsWithThis">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="PrefixCallsCorrectly">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ClosingParenthesisMustBeOnLineOfOpeningParenthesis">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="SplitParametersMustStartOnLineAfterDeclaration">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ParametersMustBeOnSameLineOrSeparateLines">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ParameterMustNotSpanMultipleLines">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="DoNotPlaceRegionsWithinElements">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
      </Rules>
      <AnalyzerSettings />
    </Analyzer>
    <Analyzer AnalyzerId="StyleCop.CSharp.SpacingRules">
      <Rules>
        <Rule Name="KeywordsMustBeSpacedCorrectly">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="SemicolonsMustBeSpacedCorrectly">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="SymbolsMustBeSpacedCorrectly">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="PreprocessorKeywordsMustNotBePrecededBySpace">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="OperatorKeywordMustBeFollowedBySpace">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="OpeningParenthesisMustBeSpacedCorrectly">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ClosingParenthesisMustBeSpacedCorrectly">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="OpeningSquareBracketsMustBeSpacedCorrectly">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ClosingSquareBracketsMustBeSpacedCorrectly">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="OpeningCurlyBracketsMustBeSpacedCorrectly">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ClosingCurlyBracketsMustBeSpacedCorrectly">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="OpeningGenericBracketsMustBeSpacedCorrectly">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ClosingGenericBracketsMustBeSpacedCorrectly">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="OpeningAttributeBracketsMustBeSpacedCorrectly">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ClosingAttributeBracketsMustBeSpacedCorrectly">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="NullableTypeSymbolsMustNotBePrecededBySpace">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="MemberAccessSymbolsMustBeSpacedCorrectly">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="IncrementDecrementSymbolsMustBeSpacedCorrectly">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="NegativeSignsMustBeSpacedCorrectly">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="PositiveSignsMustBeSpacedCorrectly">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="DereferenceAndAccessOfSymbolsMustBeSpacedCorrectly">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ColonsMustBeSpacedCorrectly">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="CodeMustNotContainMultipleWhitespaceInARow">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="CodeMustNotContainSpaceAfterNewKeywordInImplicitlyTypedArrayAllocation">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="TabsMustNotBeUsed">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
      </Rules>
      <AnalyzerSettings />
    </Analyzer>
  </Analyzers>
</StyleCopSettings>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have found my own issue. properties file should have this entry sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

Comment: If you solved your problem, you can answer your own question (yes, this is allowed and even encouraged).